# Which linux environment varaiable gives the path to the users desktop?

Tags: linux, shell, script, environment-variables

It turns out that different languages can have a path to the desktop folder.

~/Desktop is ~/Työpöytä in Finnish

What way via the shell can I get access to the translated folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs hold something like

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Työpöytä"
```

or perhaps running

```
xdg-user-dir DESKTOP
```

though I guess this depends on your distribution...

Comment: using ubuntu 9.10 the first does not exist but the second surely does, thanks.

Comment: Awesome! My guess is that the first is *somewhere* in /etc/ as a default... then you can change `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` to override it. Either way, that command is probably better. Good luck! :-)